# {$a_n$} $\in N$ .if $(a_m,a_n)=(m,n)$ when $m \ne n$,prove that $a_n=n $ for all $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

The fact is that I am not getting the question clear if $a_m=5$ and $a_n=17$ and if I take $m=3$ and $n=7$ .This doesn't hold true.Can someone help me to understand what the question is asking me ?

Answer (score 0):

There is counterexample to your statement. Let us take 
$$a_n=\begin{cases}
n^2,&& \text{if $n$ is prime}\\
n,&& \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$

If $m$ is prime then $(a_m,a_{m!})=(m^2,m!)=m=(m,m!)$. Otherwise $a_m=m$, and $a_{m!}=m!$, so the statement is evident.

Comment: I assume that `$m!=n$` in the title was meant as “not equal”, not as faculty.

Comment: ok, in that case classical proof works, of course